# App gets terminated or killed on giving permission for camera or microphone for currently running video call

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

if user denied access for camera or microphone i'm asking for permission when call received to app with custom alert

```
   func showAlertForDeniedPermissions(message:String) {
    if let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)  {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Access Needed!", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            // If camera or library settings are disabled then open general settings
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        })
        alert.addAction(okay)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If user taps okay the app settings will be opened and in background the call will be continued. 
Here if user enables permission for camera or microphone the call gets disconnected and app launches again
when i debug it shows

```
  Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```